# Pandas filldown by other column (I don't know how to name this)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data-frame with a column that indicates if the terms of an account were changed during a particular period with a value of "Y".
Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
account = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
period = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
changed = ["N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'account': account,'period': period,'changed': changed})

print(df)
    account period changed
0    1       1       N
1    1       2       N
2    1       3       N
3    1       4       Y
4    1       5       N
5    1       6       N
6    2       1       N
7    2       2       Y
8    2       3       N
9    2       4       N
10   2       5       N
11   3       1       N
12   3       2       N
13   3       3       N
```

I want to turn the changed column into a switch that once turns on, stays on for that account.  I also want the switch to be converted into 0's and 1's as shown below.

Is there a way to do this without looping through each account.  I have millions of accounts.

```
    account period  changed
0    1       1        0
1    1       2        0
2    1       3        0
3    1       4        1
4    1       5        1
5    1       6        1
6    2       1        0
7    2       2        1
8    2       3        1
9    2       4        1
10   2       5        1
11   3       1        0
12   3       2        0
13   3       3        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a `groupby` with `cumsum`  problem

```
(df.changed.eq('Y')).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().astype(int)
Out[141]: 
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    0
12    0
13    0
Name: changed, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Sorry that I relabeled my columns.  You were so quick that you already had answered.  Thanks! your solution works!  df['changed'] = (df.changed.eq('Y')).groupby(df['account']).cumsum().astype(int)

Comment: Just make sure you don't have 2 `'Y'` values for one group, otherwise you'll end up with numbers greater than 1 !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Boolean comparison and convert to `int`. Then use `GroupBy` + `cummax` to identify a change has historically occurred by `account`:

```
df['changed'] = df['changed'].eq('Y').astype(int)
df['changed'] = df.groupby('account')['changed'].cummax()

print(df)

    account  period  changed
0         1       1        0
1         1       2        0
2         1       3        0
3         1       4        1
4         1       5        1
5         1       6        1
6         2       1        0
7         2       2        1
8         2       3        1
9         2       4        1
10        2       5        1
11        3       1        0
12        3       2        0
13        3       3        0
```

Comment: what is 'ID' here?

Comment: ID is now account.  df['changed'] = (df['changed'].eq('Y')).astype(int)
df['changed'] = df.groupby('account').cummax()   This comes out as     account  period  changed
0         1       1        1
1         1       2        2
2         1       3        3
3         1       4        4
4         1       5        5
5         1       6        6
6         2       1        1
7         2       2        2
8         2       3        3
9         2       4        4
10        2       5        5
11        3       1        1
12        3       2        2
13        3       3        3

Comment: `KeyError: 'ID'`  pandas 0.20

Comment: I am wondering why `cummax` is changing with `account` and `changed`, and not dependent on `period`. when groping by `account`  aren't both `changed` and `periods` are groupded?

Comment: @astro123, See update. Not sure what happened. I think there was some confusion as you changed column labels.